# Can I run duplicates of mpi program with mpirun or in one job submit

Tags: mpi

I want to run an mpi program which typically took 2-4 processes repeatedly for dozen times.

For a serial program, I can simply run mpirun -n 24 ./hello_world. I can get the program ran in parallel for 24 times.

However, if it is an mpi program itself. Can I run a 24 mpi program in parallel, each mpi program will take 2 or 4 processes? How should I approach this?

Regards

Comment: job array is a better fit for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Runing multiple MPI programs with the same `mpirun` command will result in one large MPI job with all ranks sharing the world communicator. Not very likely what you are after. So, I'm with Gilles here -- look into job arrays.

Comment: you can use a loop in the script and in each iteration you can run MPI application.

Comment: Hi, Gilles and Hristo. Thank you, I did not know about job array before. It works for slurm now.

Comment: Hi, Maruf, thank you. But the idea is to make use of 20 cores run 5 4-processes MPI program. Using loop will make them run in sequence.